# How to set focus to a newly added row or at the end of a row in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview and an Add button. Each time I add data to the datagridview, I want it to set focus to the newly added row or at the end of it. Maybe because my datagridview always adds/inserts data at the end of it.

Here's my code for now : (I have some error in event `SelectionChanged`).

```
Boolean flag_cell_edited;
int currentRow;
int currentColumn;

private void ListView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    flag_cell_edited = true;
    currentColumn = e.ColumnIndex;
    currentRow = e.RowIndex;
}

private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(flag_cell_edited)
    {
        ListView.CurrentCell = ListView(currentColumn, currentRow);
        flag_cell_edited = false;
    }
}
```

**ADD ROWS**

```
static DataGridView _dg;
SqlDataAdapter _da;

public void Add()
    {
        sc.Open();

        try
        {
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO TableVotersInfo (Education, idnum, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, SchoolYear, ControlNum, VResult)
                                    SELECT @ed, @idnum, @firstname, @middlename, @lastname, @schoolyear, @controlnum, 'Not Voted' 
                                    WHERE @idNum NOT IN (SELECT idNum FROM TableVotersInfo);", sc))
            {
                Param();

                var rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowsAffected == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
                    FAddVoters._checkID = checkID;
                    FAddVoters._cleardata = "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Stored Successfully!");
                    FAddVoters._cleardata = cleardata;
                    FAddVoters._checkID = "0";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }


public void retList()
{
    sc.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableVotersInfo", sc);

    try
    {
        _da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        _da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
        _da.Fill(_dt);
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = _dt;
        _dg.DataSource = bs;
        _da.Update(_dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        sc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You write about datagridview but you are using listview (or you just use poorlz chosed names). So what is it? You either posted bad code or confused components.

Comment: Nope i just wanted to name it `ListView`.

Comment: Sweet, next time try to confuse us a little bit more :)

Comment: okay, sorry about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RowsAdded` event like this:

```
DataGridViewRow lastSelected;
//RowsAdded event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e){
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null) 
       dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Selected = false;
    if (lastSelected != null) lastSelected.Selected = false;
    lastSelected = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    lastSelected.Selected = true;
}
```

**NOTE**: The code is intended to use for **single added row** only. If multi rows are added, the first one of them will be selected.

Comment: It did not go to the new added row or at the very last row of datagridview. I have selectionmode set to `FullRowSelect`, maybe it's conflicting or not?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete do you know how to register the `RowsAdded` event handler? It should work. `SelectionMode` doesn't matter.

Comment: yes i know how to add event handlers. I deleted all my data from datagridview then i tried adding again. For the first and second try in adding, it still focuses. but when its at the third time it does not focus anymore.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete how do you add rows? This code should work if you add row programmatically (using code), if you add rows via the `DataGridView`, it may not be as what you expected.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete your `Add()` method just inserts new row into your database table, it doesn't update anything in your `DataGridView`, the `retList` is basically wrong. If you want to use `DataGridView` in the correct way, you have to use `DataSource` and `Update` via `DataAdapter`. All the code in `Add()` is called `dealing directly and manually with the database`, not using any kind of `Adapter` at all.

Comment: i see.. okay all clear now. I'm gonna go read more about DataSource and DataAdapter. So sad. I was about to finish my system. Just 4 days left for defense. anyways thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It'll be useful when I use `DataSource` and `DataAdapter` sooner or later. :)